# Double-edged sword synonym

Tags: synonyms

Can someone give me a few synonyms of "Double-edged sword"? I generally need a phrase that describes a situation that can go good and bad.

Comment: If you want synonyms for double-edged, you are not describing a situation that can go either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double edged sword, or a situation in which *the knife cuts on both sides*, is **not** a situation that can go good or bad. 
It is a situation in which the taken action has several effects at once.
If the effects are positive, another way of saying it is that the proposed action can *kill two birds with a stone*.

If a situation can develop either, good or bad, you can say the outcome is *doubtful*.

If you want to express that there is a risk of the situation going *really* bad, and you like the sword, you can say that *Damocles' sword* is over your head.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the use of that phrase. I was not fully aware.

Comment: Always love the anonymous down-voters :) No risk of making anything any better if you don't leave a comment :)

Comment: @AndyT Care to explain _how_ MW disagrees with me? The definition you link clearly states the situation has _both_ good _and_ bad sides, rather than having _either_ good _or_ bad effects, as the original question seemed to imply (and which was confirmed in the original asker's comment two years ago).

Comment: @oerkelens - Ah. It would appear I misread MW. I read "something that [...] can have both favorable and unfavorable consequences" as "can have favourable *or* unfavourable consequences". My bad. Previous comment deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the situation...

Sword of Damocles, robbing Peter to pay Paul, losing on the swings and gaining on the roundabouts, win some, lose some, catch 22, 2 sides of a coin, every cloud has a silver lining, poisoned chalice, wolf in sheep's clothing, all that glitters is not gold...